# JavaScript logic, button won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I've got some simplified code of mine where I can't figure out why it won't work

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <div>
        <button class="submit1">update</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <button class="submit2">submit</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="result"></div>

    <script>
        var myvar = 1;
        $(".submit1").on('click',function(){
            myvar = 2;
        });
        if(myvar == 2){
            $(".submit2").on('click',function(e){
                $('.result').html("it works!"); 

            });
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

The fact that myvar isn't 2 originally seems to essentially ignore the last part of the javascript but I don't understand why since I've never come across this kind of problem before. Any help would be appreciated!

edit(from comment): That is almost what I want, sorry I didn't specify. I have some objects that are hidden and shown and I have some more intensive code that runs when a submit button is clicked or enter is pressed on each of the hidden and shown objects. But my problem is that all of the code runs when I press enter and I tried to made an if statement to clarify which object was being shown and then only run the code if it is being shown

Comment: Your code does not make much sense. If you have a submit handler, test the value of myvar inside the one handler. What will set myVar in real life? Also make the buttons type="button" in case they ever live inside a form

Comment: Your `script` is not executed again after you click the button. So the `if` never evaluates to true

Comment: `if(myvar == 2){` can never be true, because this code is executed immediately when your page loads, whereas `myvar=2` is not executed until the user clicks the submit1 button, which of course will be later in time. I would think it would make more sense to check the value of `myvar` within the "submit2" click handler and then use that to decide what to do next.

Comment: can you tell about your flow because your code do not make sense. i think you want message to appear when button 1 then button 2 clicked. am i right ? if not please provide details.

Comment: So what method is there for writing code that would rerun the script upon a certain condition? For instance I have some objects that are hidden and shown, but I only want the script to run on objects that are shown

Comment: @doruk yes exactly that, I have some hidden and shown objects and I only want my code to run on the shown objects. Like here I was trying to make the condition simplified to if the button has been pressed, then allow the code to be run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only guess, but I believe you meant to do this?

```js
var myvar = 1;
$(".submit1").on('click', function() {
  myvar = 2;
});
$(".submit2").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.result').html(myvar == 2 ? "it works!":"Click update first");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="submit1">update</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button class="submit2">submit</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Or maybe:

```js
$(".submit1").on('click', function() {
  $(".submit2").show();
});
$(".submit2").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.result').html("it works!");
});
```

```css
.submit2 { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="submit1">update</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button class="submit2">submit</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: That is almost what I want, sorry I didn't specify. I have some objects that are hidden and shown and I have some more intensive code that runs when a submit button is clicked or enter is pressed on each of the hidden and shown objects. But my problem is that all of the code runs when I press enter and I tried to made an if statement to clarify which object was being shown and then only run the code if it is being shown.

Comment: Then please update the question with a [mcve] so we can provide a better answer

Comment: You can use `if ($("#someid").is(":visible")) { ... }`

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, I've found a similar work around with my main code, I just had a misunderstanding of how javascript would load. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A better appraoch with the existing code will be

```
    var myvar = 1;
    $(".submit1").on('click',function(){
        myvar = 2;
    });

    $(".submit2").on('click',function(e){
        if(myvar == 2){
            $('.result').html("it works!"); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Right and simple answer is:

```
    var myvar = 1;

    $(".submit1").on('click',function(){
        myvar = 2;
    });


        $(".submit2").on('click',function(e){
            if(myvar == 2){
                $('.result').html("it works!"); 
            });
        };
```